# Bson array (de)serialization with Json.NET

Tags: json.net, bson

I am simply trying to serialize and deserialize a string array in Bson format using Json.NET, but the following code fails:

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
var array = new string [] { "A", "B" };

// Serialization
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var bson = new BsonWriter(ms))
{
    jsonSerializer.Serialize(bson, array, typeof(string[]));
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

// Deserialization
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (var bson = new BsonReader(ms))
{
    // Exception here
    array = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(bson);
}
```

Exception message:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set ReadRootValueAsArray to true on BsonReader

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Bson_BsonReader_ReadRootValueAsArray.htm

This setting is required because the BSON data spec doesn't save metadata about whether the root value is an object or an array.

Answer (score 6):

Hmmm, from where I sit, your code should work, but Json.Net seems to think that your serialized array of strings is a dictionary.  This could be because, according to the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification), arrays actually do get serialized as a list of key-value pairs just like objects do.  The keys in this case are simply the string representations of the array index values.

In any case, I was able to work around the issue in a couple of different ways:

1. Deserialize to a Dictionary and then manually convert it back to an array.

   ```
   var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
   var array = new string[] { "A", "B" };

   // Serialization
   byte[] bytes;
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   using (var bson = new BsonWriter(ms))
   {
       jsonSerializer.Serialize(bson, array);
       bytes = ms.ToArray();
   }

   // Deserialization
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
   using (var bson = new BsonReader(ms))
   {
       var dict = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(bson);
       array = dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray();
   }
   ```
2. Wrap the array in an outer object.

   ```
   class Wrapper
   {
       public string[] Array { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Then serialize and deserialize using the wrapper object.

   ```
   var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
   var obj = new Wrapper { Array = new string[] { "A", "B" } };

   // Serialization
   byte[] bytes;
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   using (var bson = new BsonWriter(ms))
   {
       jsonSerializer.Serialize(bson, obj);
       bytes = ms.ToArray();
   }

   // Deserialization
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
   using (var bson = new BsonReader(ms))
   {
       obj = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Wrapper>(bson);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks or the analysis and possible work-arounds. In my case though they are a bit hard to implement as I need this code to work with unknown types. I have opened an issue on the CodePlex website: https://json.codeplex.com/workitem/24365

Comment: @XavierPoinas The second solution, wrapping the array in an outer object, works great for unknown types. Simply change the property type of the wrapper class, i.e. `public object Value { get; set; }` instead of `public string[] Array { get; set; }`, and you can use it with any non-array types as well. It's easy to create a helper class that does the wrapping/unwrapping automatically.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16949792/3744182) by [James Newton-King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11829/james-newton-king), the BSON format doesn't save metadata about whether the root value is a collection, making it necessary to set [`BsonDataReader.ReadRootValueAsArray`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/blob/a1db92678e7e72eb733f37079f3a93bfb6215338/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/BsonDataReader.cs#L105) appropriately before beginning to deserialize.

One easy way to do this, when deserializing to some known [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object) type (rather than `dynamic` or `JToken`), is to initialize the reader based on whether the root type will be serialized using an [array contract](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonArrayContract.htm).  The following extension methods do this:

```
public static partial class BsonExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeFromFile<T>(string path, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            return Deserialize<T>(stream, settings);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte [] data, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            return Deserialize<T>(stream, settings);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte [] data, int index, int count, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data, index, count))
            return Deserialize<T>(stream, settings);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        // Use BsonReader in Json.NET 9 and earlier.
        using (var reader = new BsonDataReader(stream) { CloseInput = false })  // Let caller dispose the stream
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
            //https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeFromBsonCollection.htm
            if (serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(T)) is JsonArrayContract)
                reader.ReadRootValueAsArray = true;
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```
var newArray = BsonExtensions.Deserialize<string []>(bytes);
```

Notes:

- BSON support was moved to its own package, [`Newtonsoft.Json.Bson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson), in Json.NET [10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1).  In this version and later versions [`BsonDataReader`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/BsonDataReader.cs) replaces the now-obsolete [`BsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Bson_BsonReader.htm).
- The same extension methods can be used to deserialize a dictionary, e.g.:

  ```
  var newDictionary = BsonExtensions.Deserialize<SortedDictionary<int, string>>(bytes);
  ```

  By checking the contract type `ReadRootValueAsArray` is set appropriately.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XAZBV4).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you could check data type first before set ReadRootValueAsArray to true, like this:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)) 
    bSonReader.ReadRootValueAsArray = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I discovered a easy deserialization while using the power of MongoDB.Driver

You can use BsonDocument.parse(JSONString) to deserialize a JSON object so to deserialize a string array use this:

```
string Jsonarray = "[\"value1\", \"value2\", \"value3\"]";
BsonArray deserializedArray = BsonDocument.parse("{\"arr\":" + Jsonarray + "}")["arr"].asBsonArray;
```

deserializedArray can then be used as any array such as a foreach loop.