# Can't deserialize object with collection property from BSON using Newtonsoft serializer

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, bson

I want to serialize the following objects:

```
class Zoo
{
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

class Animal
{
    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

It's not a problem to serialize/deserialize it to/from JSON using custom binder:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            Binder = binder
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zoo, settings);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Zoo>(json, settings);
```

Both BindToType/BindToName methods of my custom binder are called during serialization/deserialization.

I tried same technique with BSON but unfortunately it doesn't work. The result is not Zoo object, but JObject.
Looks like result stream doesn't contain any type information and my binder is not called during deserialization.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `BsonReadRootValueAsArray` to `true`.
James' answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16949792