# Unity Json.net bson Self referencing loop

Tags: unity-game-engine, json.net, bson

I am trying to save content in my game with Json.net. with [this](https://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2013/09/25/Json-NET-for-Unity-Developers) resource I got my game saving to JSON but now I want to save it in the Bson format as I don't want my players to be able to easily edit the save files.

Here is the code works and is saving my game data to json.

```
File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSave, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    }));
```

Here I am trying to save my game data in the bson format but I don't quite know how to turn off the ReferenceLoopHandling in the bson format.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var writer = new BsonWriter(stream);
    serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling.Equals(false);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSave);

    File.WriteAllText(path, serializer.ToString());
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error.

`JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'graph' with type 'StoryGraph'. Path 'nodes[0]'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the factory methods [`JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(JsonSerializerSettings)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_CreateDefault_1.htm) or [`JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Create_1.htm) to manufacture a serializer with your required settings, then serialize directly to a file using the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class BsonExtensions
{
    // In Json.NET 10.0.1 and later use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson
    public static void SerializeToFile<T>(T obj, string path, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        using (var writer = new BsonWriter(stream)) // BsonDataWriter in Json.NET 10.0.1 and later
        {
            JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Serialize(writer, obj);
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeFromFile<T>(string path, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        using (var reader = new BsonReader(stream)) // BsonDataReader in Json.NET 10.0.1 and later
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
            //https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeFromBsonCollection.htm
            if (serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(T)) is JsonArrayContract)
                reader.ReadRootValueAsArray = true;
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And then serialize as follows:

```
BsonExtensions.SerializeToFile(objectToSave, path, 
                               new JsonSerializerSettings 
                               { 
                                   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
                               });
```

Notes:

- Be sure to use the same settings when deserializing.
- BSON support was moved into its own package [`Newtonsoft.Json.Bson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson) in Json.NET [`10.0.1`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1).  In this version or later you should use [`BsonDataWriter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/BsonDataWriter.cs) (and [`BsonDataReader`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/BsonDataReader.cs)) as [`BsonWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Bson_BsonWriter.htm) has been made obsolete, and will eventually be removed.
- `serializer.ToString()` is not going to return the serialized BSON; instead use [`MemoryStream.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.toarray?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_MemoryStream_ToArray), i.e.

  ```
  File.WriteAllBytes(path, stream.ToArray());
  ```

  However it's more efficient to stream directly to the file as shown in the extension methods above.
- `serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling.Equals(false);` is not the correct way to set the [`ReferenceLoopHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_ReferenceLoopHandling.htm) property in c#.  Instead set it as if it were a field:

  ```
   serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
  ```

  See: [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KzDbJ1).

Comment: This almost works perfectly. I am able to serialize to Bson but unable to deserialize. I am getting this error:

Comment: JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Item]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: @AndrewPullins - that error arises when you try to deserialize a JSON object into a collection, see [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21358493).  Or if you are trying to deserialize a collection as the root object from BSON, see [Bson array (de)serialization with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16910369).  But we would need to see a [mcve] to say for sure, and your question doesn't include one.

Comment: @AndrewPullins - does setting `ReadRootValueAsArray` as shown in https://dotnetfiddle.net/KzDbJ1 fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks @dbc the ReadRootValueAsArray made it work! This is working amazingly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly set the serializer:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    // Fix: Ignore loops
    serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    ...
```

This solved the issue for me in the Unity C# context.